# How to import custom CSS in Sanity Studio v3

Tags: javascript, sanity

I would like to make a small CSS modification in Sanity Studio V3.

The old method to import CSS no longer works.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is very simple but it's not in the doc.

Create your css file.

In the file `sanity.config.ts`, import your file as follows :

`import "./custom.css";`

And test whether it works with a simple CSS statement :

```
* {
  color: red !important;
}
```

If all the text is red, it means that your import works

Comment: I was trying to setup Tailwind with Sanity Studio V3 and was wondering how to import CSS files. Thanks for the answer!